# Does QIODevice::waitForReadyRead implicitly flush the output queue (waitForBytesWritten)?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qt4, qabstractsocket

If I want to write data to a remote side and wait for its answer, I need at least a `waitForReadyRead`. But before calling that, do I need to manually flush the output queue using `waitForBytesWritten`, or does Qt automatically flush the write queue for me? I am operating synchronously (blocking) and therefore in this function I am unable to use the event loop or a local event loop.

When using `std::cin`, we can be sure that previously written bytes by `std::cout` will have been flushed. That's the analoguous situation - does it apply to Qt sockets aswell?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/19804582/), being an abstract base class, QIODevice does very little in waitForReadyRead and it's up to the implementation of inherited classes:

```
bool QIODevice::waitForReadyRead(int msecs)
{
    Q_UNUSED(msecs);
    return false;
}
```

> does it apply to Qt sockets aswell?

As you've stated that you're operating synchronously, I assume you've chosen this for a reason and are aware that on the main thread, any GUI present will freeze during a call to `waitForReadyRead`. Usually, asynchronous usage for QIODevice is preferred, with Qt being an event-driven framework.

However, the [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#details) state:

> Certain subclasses of QIODevice, such as QTcpSocket and QProcess, are asynchronous.

Therefore, if your QIODevice is a socket such as QTcpSocket, then no, you should not be required to call `waitForBytesWritten` when calling `waitForReadyRead`.

In the case of a non-synchronous device, it would be required.

Comment: Hmm, I don't understand the conclusion "Therefore, if your QIODevice is a socket such as QTcpSocket, then no, you should not be required to call waitForBytesWritten when calling waitForReadyRead". What prevents Qt from just polling or `select`-ing the socket read file descriptor for new bytes and filling its read queue? Why does being asynchronous imply that I have to flush bytes?

Comment: I was in the impression that "asynchronous" in this context means that calling write and read does not directly access the device, but read and write to buffers, that are only written from or read to when returning the the event loop or when calling one of the wait functions?

Comment: Perhaps I've misunderstood your question and please correct me if this is the case. As it stands, by asynchronous, I understand that it implies it's handled on a separate thread, so a call to waitForReadyRead, which is a blocking call, often in the main thread, won't be blocking the write process for a device such as QTcpSocket.

Answer (score 0):

I have subsequently asked Thiago Macieira (QtCore maintainer) about the subject and he replied that for QAbstractSocket, both waitForBytesWritten and waitForReadyRead will write pending bytes that were sitting in the qt buffer waiting to be handed over to the OS.

An application that does only waits for bytes to be written and only afterwards reads incoming bytes can potentially deadlock, if the remote site is blocked because of waiting for the other (local) side to read data. Because the remote side blocks, it cannot read data sent by the local side. So if the local side writes too much so that it blocks aswell, each will wait for the other to read their data and deadlock.

Therefore both the bytesWritten and readyRead wait functions process both the qt read and qt write buffer. The waitForBytesWritten may even emit the readyRead signal, which I didn't expect. So the waitForBytesWritten call essentially was redundant and can be removed.